# Sitecore Campaign Creator responds with a status of 403 (Forbidden) on page refresh

Tags: sxa

When loading the Campaign Creator for the first time, I see the 9 default Campaigns. However, if I refresh the page or leave a go back to the Campaign Creator, I just get the spinning icon and nothing loads. The console displays the following error...

> http://dev.mydomain.com/sitecore/api/ssc/CampaignManagement/Campai…oad=full&language=en&name=&startDate=&endDate=&classifications=&sc_lang=en 403 (Forbidden)

Further inspection show the following response...

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The required anti-forgery cookie \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","ExceptionType":"System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext, String cookieToken, String formToken)\r\n   at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)"}

- The __RequestVerificationToken cookie **IS** still present.
- Clearing cookies does not help.
- All configs are accounted for and appear to be correct.
- No logs of any kind have errors.
- Debugging the project reveals no exceptions

The only way I've found to get it to work is to restart the browser. It will work on initial load.

Specs:

- Sitecore 8.2 Update 4
- Sitecore Powershell Extension 4.6
- Sitecore SXA 1.4
- SOLR (Lucene has been completely disabled)

**Update:** This appears to be caused by the SXA Tenant package I was given. A fresh site has no problems after Powershell Extension 4.6 and SXA 1.4 are installed and SOLR is configured. Once I install the Tenant package, the problem occurs.

Also, deleting the Tenant resolves the problem. Even after restoring it from the Recycle Bin the problem no longer occurs, for a time. Making an update to the items in the Tenant will break it again.